# Swift: how to prevent not showed UITableViewCells from being dismissed while scrolling

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController with many cells, each of them containing a sort of input taken from user (date picker, picker view, text field and text view). When the user has finished entering the data, a proper button is tapped to save all data but the problem is that I can collect data only from the cells that are visible in the screen in the moment when tapping the button; the previous and the following ones are dismissed, their content is lost and they are ro-loaded when scrolling to that part of table. In this way I will never be able to collect all data. Is there a way to circumvent this thing and prevent those cells from being dismissed? Or is there a smarter way to get what I need?

Answer (score 2):

You should not design for the cells (views) to be responsible for holding onto your user's data. Use a data structure to store it in. How about an array?

Update:
First of all, i'm pretty sure this question has answers already but I'm on my phone so I won't try to find it. You'd do well to, however.

Think of it this way: you have no real control over when a cell is reused. But, as long as you have access to your text fields on the cells (by outlet or by using a tag), you only have to figure out a way to start listening to them when they appear on the screen.

I'm sure you can figure out where in the data source to do that, and how many text field listeners you actually need.

Comment: That's what I was thinking to do but I just have difficulty in understanding a thing: I could implement the method textFieldEditingDidEnd inside my cell swift class which contains a UITextField. So that when the user has finished typing inside the cell then that string is stored into an array o in a dictionary as you said. The problem is that: then, how can I store that text if the global array is inside the table view controller class?

Comment: There is probably no need to temporarily store anything in the cell the way you describe, as long as you have access to the cell's text fields from your controller. I'll clarify in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use NSUserDefaults to store form data like this.

```
  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(value: AnyObject?, forKey: String)
```

Now later you can get at the data this way:`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("firstCell")`

So essentially after the user is done typing, you `setObject` which would be the textField.text or textView.text property. Then set a key. Like "firstCell", "secondCell", etc.

Later you get the value by using `objectForKey("firstCell")

Comment: No need to mess with User Preferences (unless it's useful in this specific case)  a simple  `Dictionary<NSIndexPath, AnyObject>` in your datasource will do the job

Comment: @YichenBman: that sounds very interesting but If add a key to a cell, then that cell will be dismissed anyway. So even if I get the text from that cell with that key, if the cell is not in the display it will be nil. Maybe I am missing something from your answer...

Comment: @Vinzzz I was thinking to that too but I just have difficulty in understanding a thing: I could implement the method textFieldEditingDidEnd inside my cell swift class which contains a UITextField. So that when the user has finished typing inside the cell then that string is stored into an array o in a dictionary as you said. The problem is that: then, how can I store that text if the global array is inside the table view controller class?

Comment: Well, once your data & your view are separated (and you don't lose user edits when table is scrolled and cells are reused), what you do of your data is up to you! You can store it, using `NSCoding`, CoreData or any other tools. But at least, you don't have to prevent your user to scroll your list...